# C# method parameter being a property of the class

Tags: c#

First of all, apologies if I posted it in the wrong place, I'm new here and I'm not sure if I posted in the right place.
Well, I'm trying to build a generic search method, where I'll add search parameters to mount a SQL Query and execute it on the database. All that using C#. My goal is that the parameter corresponding to the field I'll search, to be a property of the class the method is in. For example:

```
public foo
{
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public void AddSearchParameter(???, EnumOperator Operator, object Value) 
}
```

Whenever I want to specify a parameter to add on the search, I would like it to look like this:

```
foo xxx = new foo();
xxx.AddSearchParameter(foo.CustomerCode, EnumOperator.Equal, txtCustomerCode.text);
```

My question is how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to pass the *member information* (so that the `AddSearchParameter` can inspect the `MemberInfo` and write suitable SQL), then you'd need to use either a string literal (i.e. `"CustomerCode"`), or an expression tree. The latter is richer, but involves learning the `Expression<T>` API. But fundamentally:

```
public void AddSearchParameter(Expression<Func<object>> expression, ...)
...
xxx.AddSearchParameter(() => foo.CustomerCode, ...)
```

This, however, is not a trivial area of .NET.

Comment: I have no problem with reflection or more complex abstract concepts, in fact, that was my first idea, but I wanted the parameter would be only showing the properties of "foo", when I use the expression you suggested, I get everything related to foo, not only the properties. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing something like this, I would probably make the `Search()` method on `foo` check for the existence of values in the various `this` properties, and then build the query based on that.

```
public List<Results> Search()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomerCode))
    {
        // add search value to query
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the way I was already doing, but turns out its not as dynamic as I wanted it to be.